# Multiple select statements into ACCESS database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

In my VB.net application I have 5 listboxes that I'm filling on form load. But I have ugly solution because for every listbox I have some FillItUp function, which opens connection, gets data from database and then populates my listbox. Problem is that I'm triggering this five times on form load.

This is my code:

```
 Public Sub FillListboxesColors()
    Try
        sqL = "SELECT * FROM Colors"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    Do While dr.Read = True
    chkColor.Items.Add(dr.Item("color"))

        Loop

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have that exact situation for every CheckedListBox.
So the question - is there a way where I can fill all listboxes in one procedure. So I'm opening connection to my database only once.

Like this...but I'm aware this is not possible with AccessDB.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Colors; SELECT * FROM Paper"
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        Do While dr.Read = True
            chkColor.Items.Add(dr.Item("color"))
            chkPaper.Items.Add(dr.Item("paper_type"))
        Loop
```

I'm asking for some helping code. Ty.

Comment: Is there anything that connects paper and colors? some ID or identifieer

Comment: No, this are tables without relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The following C# code shows one way that you could populate your listboxes using just one database connection:

```csharp
using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    con.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Color] FROM [Colors]", con))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is where you would .Add '{0}' to the .Items for chkColor.", rdr["Color"]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Size] FROM [Sizes]", con))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("This is where you would .Add '{0}' to the .Items for chkSize.", rdr["Size"]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

The program output is:

```
This is where you would .Add 'Red' to the .Items for chkColor.
This is where you would .Add 'Green' to the .Items for chkColor.
This is where you would .Add 'Blue' to the .Items for chkColor.

This is where you would .Add 'Small' to the .Items for chkSize.
This is where you would .Add 'Medium' to the .Items for chkSize.
This is where you would .Add 'Large' to the .Items for chkSize.
```

You would simply replace the `Console.WriteLine` statements inside the `while` loops with `chkColor.Items.Add` statements (and tweak the C# syntax to VB.NET syntax).